# How can I do the following regex in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

how do i match each of the following with regex ?

`some text includes [any number of character].` need to pull the entire *[asdfasdf]*

`@tableid='sometext'` I need to pull the *sometext*

`mary and drugs` I need to pull " and ", spaces included.

Answer (score 2):

```
irb(main):002:0> "some text include [abcdef]".match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1]
=> "abcdef"

irb(main):005:0> "@table_id='2356'".match(/'(.*)'/)[1]
=> "2356"

irb(main):006:0> "mary and drugs".match(/mary(.*)drugs/)[1]
=> " and "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
"\[(.*?)\]"
"@\w+='(.*?)'"
" +and +"
```